# How can I update data with the same ID in a single PUT method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, api

I have 3 tables on database

```
public class RawMaterial
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int RawId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string RawName { get; set; }
    public int RawNumber { get; set; }

}
```

```
public class Product
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int ProductNumber { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Stock
{
    [Key]
    public int StockId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Product")]
    public int ProdutctId { get; set; }
    public Produtct Produtct { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RawMaterial")]
    public int RawId { get; set; }
    public RawMaterial RawMaterial { get; set; }
    public int StockNumber { get; set; }
}
```

```
public void CreateRawMaterial(int id)
{
    using (var projeDbContext = new ProjeDbContext())
    {
        var RawCreate = projeDbContext.Stock.Where(d => d.ProductId.Equals(id)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (RawCreate != null)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

If the entered Id is equal to the ProductId, I want the raw materials with that ProductId to increase by 100. I wrote this far, but after that I got an error.

I have 3 tables, my stock table has 2 foreign keys, one is ProductID and the other is RawId, so I want the value of my materials whose Id and ProductId are equal to increase by 100. There are more than 1 material with the same ProductId.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I am getting System.NullReferenceException error and I couldn't find how to increment data with same id.

Comment: Best is maybe to debug... where do you exactly get the NullReferenceException? Normally this happens if you didn't assign a variable correctly -> it is null

Comment: See the doc : [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/)